# How to transfer a variable that contains a java or python code from php file to an empty file (.java or .py)?

Tags: java, php, python

Please I want to transfer a code from the variable $s to an empty file that ends (.java or .py). Please, can you help? Any hint?

```
<?php

$solution=$_GET['solution'];//i get this solution from outside
$PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin";
$s=$solution;
//$u=implode("",$s0 );

    echo "<br />";
    echo exec("javac $s.java 2>&1");
    echo "<br />";
    echo exec("java $s 2>&1");
    echo "<br />";
    echo shell_exec("javac $s.java 2>&1 ");
    echo "<br />";
    ?>
```

Comment: Hint: your question isn't really about Java, all you're wanting to know is how to create a file in PHP.

Comment: but what I need is compiling a java program using php. I'm getting the java code as a text. But I need to convert it as a java code (ends in .java). Then, compile it

Comment: what is "a java code"?

Comment: Does $_GET['solution'] contain a complete executable java code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using php version 5.x.x, then..

What you are lookingfor is **[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)**.

```
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

So your code should use it as below(from what I understood), by assembling/concatenating all the file content in a variable(lets say $final), **in string format**, then using afore mentioned function.

```
<?php
.......
$file = 'sample.java';
file_put_contents($file, $final);

?>
```

Comment: Feel free to ask any questions/ clear any confusion.

Comment: Also, please feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer) if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: create an empty file on the file system using php (see [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))

Step 2: write the code out to the file (see [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php))

Step 3: close the file (see [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php))

Step 4: compile the Java file based on the name of the file you used in fopen

Step 5: keep going :)

Comment: I used the first and got empty     {<?php

$solution=$_GET['solution'];//i get this solution from outside
$PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin";
$s=$solution;
//$u=implode("",$s0 );

    echo "<br />";
    echo exec("javac $s.java 2>&1");
    echo "<br />";
    echo exec("java $s 2>&1");
    echo "<br />";
    echo shell_exec("javac $s.java 2>&1 ");
    echo "<br />";
    ?>}

Comment: I also tried this one and got a message saying i don't permissions to open, while i gave all permissions by using chmod 777. If I go to the file's properties, I can see that all permissions are checked. Can anyone help me with this?                                                                                                             <?p    $myFile = 'temp.py';
echo ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!file_exists($myFile)) {
  print 'File not found';
}
else if(!$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')) {
  print 'Can\'t open file';
  
}
else {
  print 'Success open file';
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

The code below generates a file named myFile.java which contains "Your Java Code" under C:\Program Files.

The name "myFile" is based on the parameter $s.

And of course myFile.java will not be compiled successfully by javac. Because it contains invalid java code.

I'm not sure if the special characters (e.g., "[, ], /, /, ;, (, ), " ) in a java code will cause some problems with fwrite(). So I don't think it's a good idea to pass a complete java code by $_GET.

```
<?php
$solution="Your Java Code";
$PATH="C:\\Program Files\\";

// $s=$solution; // $s is the java file name, you shouldn't assign a java code ($solution) to your java file name
$s = "myFile";

$file = fopen($PATH . $s . ".java", "w");
fwrite($file, $solution);
fclose($file);

echo "<br />";
echo exec("javac $s.java 2>&1");
echo "<br />";
echo exec("java $s 2>&1");
echo "<br />";
echo shell_exec("javac $s.java 2>&1 ");
echo "<br />";

?>
```

Comment: @Ghilas Is this what you want to do?

Comment: what I want to do is transferring a string from my php file to a java file. My java file is empty so I can call it in my php, then compile it. I used your code and it didn't transfer anything. The file is still empty and nothing was compiler. I used fopen , fwrite and fclose function and still does not give anything. I also used file_input_contents and didn't work. I gave all permissions to my file (x,r,w) and still nothing happened.

Comment: I tried this code too: {   $myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);     }//It says can't open file. I really don't know how to solve this simple thing

Comment: I also tried this code. It says Can't open file!!!!
<?php   $myFile = 'temp.py';
if (!file_exists($myFile)) {
  print 'File not found';
}
else if(!$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w')) {
  print 'Can\'t open file';
}
else {
  print 'Success open file';
}
?>